# How to extract the rows that contain the desired strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to extract the rows based on the list of string as words, phrases etc. My questions are as follow:

1. Do I need to write this code every single time to exact?
2. What codes can I write to generate a new variable after this `for` loop?

Here is what I tried.

```
fruit=['apple','banana','orange']
b1=[]
b2=[]
b3=[]
for i in range(len(df)):
    SelecgtedWords='apple'
    if SelectedWord in df.loc[i,'text']:
        a1=df.loc[i,'title']
        a2=df.loc[i,'text']
        a3=df.loc[i,'label']
        a4=df.loc[i,'author']
        b1.append(a1)
        b2.append(a2)
        b3.append(a3)
        b4.append(a4)

new_df=pd.DataFrame(columns=[title,'text','label','author'])

new_df['title']=b1
new_df['text']=b2
new_df['label']=b3
new_df['author']=b4
```

It's basically like an Excel filter function, but I want to automate the process.

Comment: You can use the dataframe.filter function to do this without the for loop. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: Try `new_df =  df['text'].str.contains('apple|banana|orange', regex=True)`

Comment: Thanks @DamiãoMartins ; BTW, do you know how to write a code to classify topics based on the list of keywords? Like if this contain apples, then create a variable. Because I have a list of 100 keywords. Not sure how to do that. I'm still figuring out.

Comment: @shenghong zhong You meant separate the dataframes based on each keyword? A dict could be used, the keyword as the key and the dataframe as the value.

Comment: @DamiãoMartins that's a good idea.I'll try it. However, I aim to achieve automate classify datasets into different sub-dataset. The annoying thing is I don't know until I saw it one by one. e.g. I didn't know people would talk about the brand "Apple" until I saw it. It's called the 'Inductive method" to classify data. So I have to filter out them manually. I always wonder if there is an algorithm or I can write one. I searched for tutorials and courses for a long time, but none of them is helpful directly. Thanks for your answers anyway.

Comment: @shenghong zhong I see, what you need is way more complex then I thinking. Maybe Machine Learning clustering/classification algorithms could help.

Comment: @DamiãoMartins yes,  I was trying to combine the solutions from the textbook "Hands-on machine learning" But I have no luck. that's really cool. You mentioned spacy. I listened one of podcast called "Practical A.I" where the founder of this package explained this package was the product of his PhD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not need the for loop to do that. Complementing the @Mike67 sugestion:

```
fruit=['apple','banana','orange']
new_df = df.loc[df['text'].str.contains('|'.join(fruit), regex=True)]
```

Comment: Thanks. What if there are values returns like " I like Apple brand so much." which is not what I really want, fruit "apple". How do you filter out them?

Comment: @shenghongzhong  You meant because the case sensitive or you want only match exact text?

Comment: That's a good point. How do I make it not case-sensitive? sometimes, it'll bring you irrelevant data. I'd like to see the text associated with the fruit "apple" rather than "Apple" as the brand.

Comment: Use the flag re.IGNORECASE `str.contains('|'.join(fruit), flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)`. But this way `Apple` will match `apple` as well. To understand the context wich the word are used, you will need a natural language processing, such https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend

Comment: that's cool. I'm wondering how long it will take if I'm writing an algorithm to identify the context. Thanks @DamiãMartins

Comment: @shenghong zhong An opensource option is the https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101